# How does bootstrap 3 set template image?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with django and bootstrap3.  I've downloaded a template from from http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/landing-page/ . The github repo is https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap-landing-page/blob/gh-pages/index.html

This contains The following in the index.html:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="intro-message">
                    <h1>Landing Page</h1>
                    <h3>A Template by Start Bootstrap</h3>
                    <hr class="intro-divider">
                    <ul class="list-inline intro-social-buttons">
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://twitter.com/SBootstrap" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">Twitter</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-github fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">Github</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">Linkedin</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

</div>
<!-- /.intro-header -->
```

How is the introductory photo included here. I see the stock photo  at https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap-landing-page/blob/gh-pages/img/intro-bg.jpg . I assume this is some bootstrap3 magic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the correct url in the `landing-page.css`

```
 .intro-header {
  background: url(../img/intro-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
   background-size: cover;
 }
```

thats it